# Как узнать находится ли курсор в форме?

Tags: c#

Необходимо понять находится ли курсор мыши на данный момент в форме, как лучше всего это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - `bool` переменная, работающая с обработчиками событий формы `MouseMove`/`MouseEnter`  и `MouseLeave`. В обработчике `MouseMove`/`MouseEnter` записывайте в вашу переменную `true`, а в обработчике `MouseLeave` - `false`. Таким образом, обращаясь к переменной вы будете знать, находится ли курсор на форме либо нет.

Comment: Заводим курсор на форму - сработал MouseEnter. Жмём Alt+Tab, переключаясь на другое приложение, сдвигаем курсор. Жмём Alt-Tab, возвращаясь в наше приложение. Оно считает, что курсор в форме (потому что MouseLeave не было), а на деле не так.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov предложите свой вариант, возможно он окажется более универсальным.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Все получилось

Answer (score 4):

Свойство `MousePosition` возвращает позицию мыши в экранных координатах.

Методом `PointToClient` преобразуем экранные координаты в координаты контрола/формы.

Далее проверяем, попадают ли эти координаты в границы формы.

```
var point = PointToClient(MousePosition);
var isInForm = ClientRectangle.Contains(point);
```